# How to to branch the query among multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, informix

If i have 4 tables like this :

```
1- mainemployees

emp_id
email
type (0-->ext,1-->internal,2--->special)
```

---

```
2-externalemp

emp_id
name

3-internalemp

emp_id
name

4-specialemp

emp_id
name
```

---

Now i want all the `employee names`
where the emp_id of the first table = the emp_id of one of the last three tables 
how to do do this (performance wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  nvl(ee.name, nvl(ie.name, se.name))
from    mainemployees me
left join
        externalemp ee
on      ee.emp_id = me.emp_id
left join
        internalemp ie
on      ie.emp_id = me.emp_id
left join
        specialem se
on      se.emp_id = me.emp_id
where   nvl(ee.name, '') <> ''
        or nvl(ie.name, '') <> ''
        or nvl(se.name, '') <> ''
```

Comment: What's the alternative to `coalesce` in `informix` cuz i get syntax error when i try that method .

Comment: Informix seems to use `nvl` as its `coalesce` alternative

Comment: but when i use `NVL` it takes two params not three params

Comment: Yeah, so you have to use it twice, f.e. `nvl(ee.name, nvl(ie.name, se.name))`

Comment: `Is[Not] NULL Predicate may be used only with simple Columns`

Comment: Informix is pretty restrictive!  You can check for `null` using `nvl`, perhaps that works, edited in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table mainemployees (emp_id int, emp_type int)

create table externalemp (emp_id int, name nvarchar(20))

create table internalemp (emp_id int, name nvarchar(20))

create table specialemp (emp_id int, name nvarchar(20))

insert into mainemployees (emp_id, emp_type) values (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)

insert into externalemp (emp_id, name) values (1, 'external')
insert into internalemp (emp_id, name) values (2, 'internal')
insert into specialemp (emp_id, name) values (3, 'special')
```

And for the query you use CASE to select right column

```
SELECT 
    CASE me.emp_type WHEN 0 THEN ee.name WHEN 1 THEN ie.name WHEN 2 THEN se.name END 
FROM mainemployees as me
LEFT JOIN externalemp as ee ON me.emp_id = ee.emp_id 
LEFT JOIN internalemp as ie ON me.emp_id = ie.emp_id 
LEFT JOIN specialemp as se ON me.emp_id = se.emp_id
```